# How to find the latest date from the given map value in java

Tags: java, date, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm having hash map with below values, in values I've date as string data type. I would like to compare all the dates which is available in map and extract only one key-value which has a very recent date.

I would like to compare with values not keys.

I've included the code below

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
      map.put("1", "1999-01-01");
      map.put("2", "2013-10-11");
      map.put("3", "2011-02-20");
      map.put("4", "2014-09-09");

      map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key : " + k + " Value : " + v));
    }

}
```

The expected output for this one is:

Key 4 Value 2014-09-09

Comment: he needs the largest value, not key

Comment: OK, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values

Comment: Design error. Don’t put your dates into your map as strings. Put `LocalDate` objects. The rest of the code will probably be the same, save declaration of the type of the map.

Comment: Related: [Finding the keys of map with the highest values (equality may occur)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153346/finding-the-keys-of-map-with-the-highest-values-equality-may-occur) (on Stack Exchange Code Review).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should provide the newest (aka largest) date as compared to the others.

```java
      String max = map.values().stream().reduce("0000-00-00",
            (a, b) -> b.compareTo(a) >= 0 ? b
                  : a);
```

If you also want the key, then do this and return a Map.Entry.  Requires Java 9+

```java
         Entry<String, String> ent =
            map.entrySet().stream().reduce(Map.entry("0", "0000-00-00"),
                  (a, b) -> b.getValue().compareTo(a.getValue()) >= 0 ? b
                        : a);

         System.out.println(ent.getKey() + " -> " ent.getValue());
```

This presumes your map is non-empty.  if it is empty, then it returns a null. Works with Java 8+

```java
        Entry<String, String> ent = map.entrySet().stream().reduce(
            (a, b) -> b.getValue().compareTo(a.getValue()) >= 0 ? b
                  : a).orElseGet(() -> null);
```

Comment: How to get the key as a result?

Comment: See my addition.  Thought you just wanted the value.  Mea Culpa.

Comment: I'm getting an error with your new code - Map.entry("0", "0000-00-00") - it says Method map.entry is undefined for the type Map..

Comment: You must be running something older than Java 9 (which is when that was added).  I will offer an alternative and explain it.

Comment: Yes I'm using Java 8

Answer (score 5):

Use [Collections.max](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator)) with [entrySet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet)

```
Entry<String, String> max = Collections.max(map.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
```

or

```
Entry<String, String> max = Collections.max(map.entrySet(),
    new Comparator<Entry<String, String>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<String, String> e1, Entry<String, String> e2) {
            return LocalDate.parse(e1.getValue()).compareTo(LocalDate.parse(e2.getValue()));
        }
});
```

Comment: The `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` is nifty (since Java 8).

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
    Optional<Map.Entry<String, String>> result = map.entrySet().stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));
    System.out.println(result);
```

output is `Optional[4=2014-09-09]`

Comment: Thanks, dear.. but I'm looking for the key in result

Answer (score 3):

At the first glance, using String literals to represent Date is not a good approach and makes it more fragile and error prone. You would rather use `LocalDate` in the first place. However, with the assumption that you don't have any control over that data format (for instance, say, it is coming from another third party system), we can still devise an approach that solves the problem at hand. Here's how it looks.

```
Entry<String, String> maxEntry = map.entrySet().stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparing(e -> LocalDate.parse(e.getValue())))
    .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
```

The `LocalDate.parse` is used to convert the string representation of the date into a `LocalDate` which is a Comparable. That `Comparable` is then passed as a key to the `Comparator` construction method. And here's the output key-value pair upon the successful execution:

```
4=2014-09-09
```

If you can merely dispense with the String representation of date as suggested above, then you can make the above solution much more simpler and succinct.

```
Entry<String, LocalDate> maxEntry = map.entrySet().stream()
    .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the string into `LocalDate` and sort it in reverse order

```
 Entry<String, String> res = map.entrySet()
                                .stream()
                                .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Entry<String, String> entry)->LocalDate.parse(entry.getValue())).reversed())
                                .findFirst()
                                .orElse(null);  // if not present return null or empty Entry
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do either :

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;

Entry<String, String> maxEntry = map.entrySet()
                                    .stream()
                                    .max(Entry.comparingByValue());
                                    .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
```

or :

```
Entry<String, String> max = Collections.max(map.entrySet(), Entry.comparingByValue());
```

Both will produce the same result.

Comment: The `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` is nifty (since Java 8).